# how to find duplicate records in a table within a predefined time period in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

For example, i have following table

```
Mobile number  Timestamp  
123456         17-09-2015 11:30 
455677         17-09-2015 12:15
123456         17-09-2015 12:25  
453377         17-09-2015 13:15
```

If now is 11:30, I want to scan my table and find rows with the same numbers within the past 1 hour.

That's my SQL statement:

```
select a.number, a.time
from mytable a inner join
     (select number, time
      from mytable b
      where time>=now()-Interval 1 hour and time<=now ()
      group by number
      Having count(*) > 1
     ) b
     on a.number = b.number and a.time = b.time
```

I want to find duplicate rown with the same numbers happening within 1 hour. I should output the number and timestamp.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to find duplicate rown with the same numbers happening within 1 hour. I should output the number and timestamp.

Comment: added question from comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using `exists`?

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.time >= now() - Interval 1 hour and
      t.time <= now() and
      exists (select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t2.number = t.number and
                    t2.time >= now() - Interval 1 hour and
                    t2.time <= now () and
                    t2.time <> t.time
             );
```

However, I suspect that the problem with your query is the join to `time`.  Just remove the time from the subquery and the `on` clause and you will get all numbers.  Alternatively, use `group by`:

```
select t.number, group_concat(time)
from mytable t
where t.time >= now() - Interval 1 hour and
      t.time <= now() 
group by t.number
having count(*) > 1;
```